# After rotate the image increases in size

Tags: php

I get a strange behaviour...

Using this script for image manipulation (rotation), every time I use the image size increases.

e.g. after using it twice the image changes from **168.4** to **53.2 Kb**.

```
$image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_u);
$rotate = imagerotate($image_source, $angle, 0);
imageinterlace($rotate, true);

unlink($path_u);
imagejpeg($rotate, $path_u, 100);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

There is something wrong or are the gd functions that make this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
imagejpeg($rotate, $path_u, 100);
```

If you are saving it with 100% quality it will take more disk space, even if the quality will stay the same

Comment: Man, beat me by four seconds. +1

Comment: but if you let the quality to 75% (default) every time I rotate the image lose quality ..
is that correct?

Comment: @ceejayoz - It happens sometimes ;)

Comment: @user2126724 - It is true, but if you are pending just one operation on the image it shouldn't be noticeable. If you are making bunch of edits, just try to make them in one session (open file -> edits -> save file)

Answer (score 0):

You've set a quality setting of 100%. The original image was likely created with a lower quality setting.